# Bound on non-sublinear function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the following function $\varphi(x)=(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x$ which is convex and non-decreasing on the positive axis. Also, it is clearly not sublinear.
I am, however, given $a>0$ trying to upper-bound $\varphi(a\cdot x)$ with $a$ and functional of $\varphi$ and $x$.
More precisely, I'd like to have a bound of the following shape: $$\varphi(a\cdot x) \leq a \varphi(\psi(x)).$$ In case $0<a<1$ I can use the convexity of $\varphi$ to say that $\varphi(a\cdot x) \leq a \varphi(x)$. In case $a>1$ the best I could do was saying that $\varphi(a \cdot x)\leq a\cdot x^2$.
Do you think it's possible to provide a unified bound for $a>0$ of the form:
\begin{equation}
\varphi(a \cdot x) \leq a \varphi(\psi(x)),\end{equation}
for some $\psi$? How would you approach the problem?

Comment: Technically $ax^2$ is also of that form, if you choose $\psi(x) = \varphi^{-1}(x^2)$, where $\varphi^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\varphi$ restricted to the positive axis. So why not just choose $\psi(x)$ as the maximum of $x$ and $\varphi^{-1}(x^2)$?

Comment: Yes, I could, but I was looking for something tighter and maintain $\varphi$ on the right-hand side.